# How to use Android functionality in web app like "progressive web app"

Tags: android, web-applications, bluetooth, progressive-web-apps, android-usb

I have developed hybrid mobile applications, there I am able to use Android functionalities like USB connectivity, Bluetooth connectivity etc.

Now I want to develop same app as web app which will run on desktop browsers and mobile browsers, but the problem is that I am not able to use Android functionalities i.e. USB connectivity and Bluetooth connectivity.

I have tried for Java applet but did not work.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: please go through this --https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web

Comment: keep in mind that web bluetooth is not widely supported yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-bluetooth

Comment: Its not going to happen for iOS.  They are not supporting bluetooth API

Comment: WebUSB API has been created to provide a way to expose USB device services to the Web. It available in Chrome 61 and works with HTTPS only. For more information you can check: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web